# Conditional Linq to XML select (nested select statements)

Tags: xml, linq, facebook, select, facebook-fql

I'm trying to view all my friends from facebook who went to some school. I use FQL to get an xml file that contains all my friends with their education info. But i can't use FQL to select only those who went to the same school. Therefor, I'm trying to use Linq to XML to select only the users i want. I've tried some methods but those won't work for me.

Here is my linq query:

```
XDocument doc = RemoveNamespace (XDocument.Load(url));

        string[] search = {"Katho", "katho", "kortrijk" , "vhti"};
       List<string> keys = new List<string>( search );



        var user = (from usr in doc.Descendants("user")

                                   select new fbUser
                                   {

                                       name = usr.Element("name").Value,

                                       email = usr.Element("email").Value,
                                       current_location = StringExtensions.checkNull(usr.Element("current_location").Value,""),
                                       hometown_location = usr.Element("hometown_location").Value,
                                       pic = StringExtensions.checkNull(usr.Element("pic_square").Value,"http://www.fox16.com/media/avatar/default.jpg"),
                                       education_history = (from edu in usr.Descendants("education_info")
                                                           //where usr.Element("education_history").HasElements
                                                           where keys.Contains(edu.Element("name").Value)
                                                           select new Education
                                                           {

                                                               name = StringExtensions.checkNull(edu.Element("name"),""),
                                                               year = StringExtensions.checkNull(edu.Element("year"),""),
                                                               school_type = StringExtensions.checkNull(edu.Element("school_type"),""),
                                                               concentrations = from conc in edu.Descendants("concentrations")
                                                                                where (edu.Element("concentrations").HasElements)
                                                                                select new Concentration
                                                                                {
                                                                                    name = StringExtensions.checkNull(conc.Element("concentration").Value, "")
                                                                                }
                                                           })

                                   }).Take(5)
                                   ;
```

EDIT: sample xml can be found here:[sample XML](http://pastebin.com/ayVUZL2x)

There's one more problem. The school name is not an direct attribute from the fbUser object. Also in the xml file  the schoolname can only be found here

```
<user><education_history><education_info><name>
```

So here is my where statement:

```
where usr.Element("education_history").Element("education_info").Element(name").value == "schoolname"
```

Problem is that there is not always an education_history or education_info node in the xml.

So i also need a way to work around this..

Any help on this problem is very appreciated.

I hope you can help me!

Grtz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're referring to a `where` statement on users, which is not present in your sample. The top query (`select new fbUser`) performs a select on all users. If you want to filter your user list, you need to insert a `where` statement between the `from` and `select`, like this:

```
    var user = (from usr in doc.Descendants("user")
            where usr.Element("education_history") != null
                && usr.Element("education_info").Element(name") != null
                && usr.Element("education_info").Element(name").value == "schoolname"

            select new fbUser
            {
                //...
            }
```

Also, a common misconception made when stranslating data queries into LinQ is that the resulting LinQ query should be a single statement, which it doesn't have to be. In your case, the query isn't executed until you use the `Take(5)` statement. So if you have trouble constructing your `where` statement, you can postpone it until after you've created the `select` part:

```
var query = (from usr in doc.Descendants("user")
             select new fbUser
                   //...

var user = query.where(u => 
    u.Element("education_history") != null
        && u.Element("education_info").Element(name") != null
        && u.Element("education_info").Element(name").value == "schoolname"
).Take(5);
```

Comment: Thx for the fast reply! I've not found it completly, but i guess i'm getting very close now.

Comment: i've edited my question. If you would mind take a second look? Your help is very appreciated!

Comment: Updated the `where` statements in my code samples based on your edit.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer needed only a small correction.

Comment: What was the correction? If you put it in a comment, I'll update the answer for you.

Comment: where usr.Element("education_history").HasElements
                                        && usr.Element("education_history").Element("education_info").Element("name") != null
                                        && usr.Element("education_history").Element("education_info").Element("name").Value == "SCHOOLNAME"
                                       select new fbUser